# A Hausdorff locally convex space is normable iff it can be generated by a finite subfamily of seminorms.

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Suppose $X$ is a Hausdorff locally convex space, then we know its topology can be generated by a family of seminorms. Let us call $P$ to this defining family of seminorms on $X$. I need to show that X is normable iff $P$ is equivalent to a finite subfamily $P_0 \subset P$.

To prove it, we of course now that $P_0$ is dominated by $P$ (in the topological sense), i.e. that every open in $P_0$ is open in $P$. So we can reformulate our question by stating that $X$ is normable iff $P$ is dominated by a family subfamily of seminorms.

Using [Kolmogorov's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_normability_criterion) I have shown the right to left implication. That is, we assume $P$ can be generated by a finite family of seminorms, and then we can prove that a convex bounded neighborhood of $0$ exists. We can pick and fix any $\epsilon>0$ and let $A$ be the convex hull of $\cup_{i=1}^n p_{\epsilon,i}$ (the union of the $\epsilon$ balls of the $n$ seminorms that generate the topology on $X$. Then it is by construction convex and around 0 and we just need to check it is bounded. I have done this.

Can you help me with the reverse implication? What is some clearer property that the seminorms must have because the space is normable? Maybe I can use this to prove that $P$ is dominated by $P_0$. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $(X,\tau)$ is normable, let $p$ be the norm on $X$. Suppose $\tau$ is induced by a family of seminorms $(p_i)_{i\in I}$. Let $B$ be the open unit ball w.r.t $p$.

Basic neighborhoods of zero are described as
$$ W(\varepsilon, i_1,\ldots, i_n) := \{x\in X \mid \max _{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}|p_{i_k}(x)| \leqslant \varepsilon\} \quad (i_k\in I,\ n\in\mathbb N, 
 \quad\varepsilon>0) $$
Pick a basic NH of zero contained in $B$ and show that those seminorms induce $\tau$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not sure though I follow the idea of your proof. Once that I check that $p_U$ is a norm inducing the topology on $X$, how does it follow that $P$ is equivalent to a finite subset of seminorms?

Comment: @Sarah misread your question at first. Revised.

Comment: Thanks. I am however stucked.. To prove the topologies are the same, we can try to show that if a sequence converges to 0 in this basic neighborhood topology, then it does in the original one and conversely. Then the identity map would be continuous and its inverse also at 0, and hence the spaces homeomorphic. Can you indicate why if it soncerges in the basic neighborhood topology then it does on the original one?

Comment: And are you saying that any subset of seminorms induce the topology?

Comment: @Sarah your proof idea is a correct one. These basic subsets are a nh basis of zero in $\tau$. That's already known. No, not any subset.

Comment: Dear Alvin, could you be more explicit in the concrete set of seminorms I have to consider? Is it those given by your $W$? I mean should I keep them fixed?

Comment: @Sarah Yes, we pick a $W$ corresponding to some $p_{i_1} ,\ldots, p_{i_n}$. Then we show that the NH basis of zero induced by the fixed seminorms also induces $\tau$.